# Download a file from BOX SDK iOS

Tags: ios, download, sdk, box

I need to download an image from the BOX sdk into my app. I have this already working using the dropbox sdk - seems easier than Box sdk. Anyway - I have a delegate method returning the name of the file but how do I actually download the file?

```
    - (void)itemsViewController:(BOXItemsViewController *)itemsViewController didTapFile:(BOXFile *)file inItems:(NSArray *)items {

    NSLog(@"Did tap file: %@", file.name);

    BOXFileDownloadRequest *downloadRequest;
    BOXContentClient *contentClient;

    contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
    downloadRequest = [_contentClient fileDownloadRequestWithID:file.name toOutputStream:outputStream];
    [_downloadRequest performRequestWithProgress:^(long long totalBytesTransferred, long long totalBytesExpectedToTransfer) {
    } completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSData *data = [outputStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            _uiiv_logo.image = img;
        }
        else{
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: What issue do you have with the posted code?

Comment: Nothing downloads. I've tried switching to BoxItem to get the jsondict to see the url but they a reblank. I think I need to enable sharing. I tried that and the urls now show but still nothing downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up casting to BOXItem to get the 'id'.

```
- (void)itemsViewController:(BOXItemsViewController *)itemsViewController didTapFile:(BOXFile *)file inItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    BOXItem *item = file;
    BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NSURLSession.png"];

    BOXFileDownloadRequest *boxRequest = [contentClient fileDownloadRequestWithID:[item.JSONData valueForKey:@"id"] toLocalFilePath:localFilePath];
    [boxRequest performRequestWithProgress:^(long long totalBytesTransferred, long long totalBytesExpectedToTransfer) {
        // Update a progress bar, etc.
        NSLog(@"progress %lld",totalBytesTransferred);
    } completion:^(NSError *error) {
        // Download has completed. If it failed, error will contain reason (e.g. network connection)
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"customUpdateBG" object:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```